# Modulus of first order ODE increasing implies solution convex up

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Consider the ODE $$y'=g(y)$$
Show that if $|g(y)|$ is increasing or decreasing in some interval then the solution in that interval is concave up or concave down, accordingly.

My approach:

Consider $y\in (a,b)$ implies $|g(y)|$ is increasing. Then $|y'|$ is also increasing for $y\in (a,b)$. $(a,b)$ must contain the point $y_0$ satisfying $g(y_0)=0=y'(x_0)$ for some point $x_0$ where the slope of the solution is zero. Since $|g(y)|$ is increasing on $(a,b)$, |y'| is also increasing on $(a,b)$, so that $|y''|$ is increasing on $(a,b)$ as well. Thus $|y''(x_0)|$ is increasing. However, $y''(x_0)$ may be greater than $0$ or it can be less than $0$.

So how can we say that the solution is necessarily concave up if $|g(y)|$ is increasing, but $g(y)$ is negative on $(a,b)$?

Comment: what are the conditions on $g$? if you are taking two derivatives on $y$ this means something for $g$ as well.

Comment: No specific conditions on $g$ were given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is $y_0 \in (a, b)$ such that $g(y_0) = 0$ then $\lvert g \rvert$ cannot be increasing or decreasing on $(a, b)$.  So, either $g$ is positive and increasing on $(a, b)$ (which implies that the solution is increasing and concave up), or it is negative and decreasing (which implies that the solution is decreasing and concave down), or else $g$ is positive and decreasing, etc, etc.

Comment: So, actually if a solution $y(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$ and if it is located under the axis of ordinates on $(a,b)$, and if it is concave up, then $|g|$ will be decreasing. It may also be concave down with $|g|$ increasing... I'm wondering if the question posed as I found it is actually correct.

Comment: Sorry, I botched my answer.  If $g$ is negative and $\lvert g \rvert$ is increasing then $g$ is decreasing.  But one has to consider the composite function, $x \mapsto y(x) \mapsto g(y(x))$.  The composition of two decreasing functions is increasing, so the solution is _concave up_, not down!  Similarly, if $g$ is negative and $\lvert g \rvert$ is decreasing then $g$ is increasing.  The composition of an increasing and a decreasing function is decreasing, so the solution is concave down.  So, everything seems O.K.